# A Wrapper's LIST<AnotherWrapperClass> isn't setting

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a VF controller (similar to the following) with two types of classes:

1. **Outer Wrapper Class** `benefitSection` - to hold section data
2. **Inner Wrapper Class** `benefitChoice` - to hold Line Item data

Within each section, there is a `List<benefitChoice>` called `availableList`.  `benefitChoice` is a basic wrapper (`boolean` + `record`) to record which `benefitChoice`s are selected.

I use an `apex:repeat` to loop over the availableList, but when I refresh the page using a commandAction (by using the method returnNull or one that actually does something meaningful), the `benefitChoice`'s `selelected` values aren't setting to the controller.  (After the refresh/reRender, **ALL** of the checkboxes are `false` whether or not they have been checked.)

All my class variables are `public {get;set;}`, and I thought the VF page will set all `List` variables back to the controller (but it won't honor `maps`).  I'm kinda stuck at the moment.

VF Page:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <apex:repeat value="{!medicalSection.availableList}" var="b">
            <div>
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!b.selected}"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <apex:outputField value="{!b.benefit.Item_Description__c}"/>
            </div>
        </apex:repeat>
        <br/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!returnNull}" value="Submit"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller:

```
public Cntrlr_SelectWhatYouWant{
    public benefitSection medicalSection {get;set;}    
    public benefitSection dentalSection {get;set;}
    public benefitSection flexSection {get;set;}
    // etc...

    public benefitSection {  // OUTER wrapper 
         public string sectionRecordType {get;set;}
         list<benefitChoice> availableList {get;set;}

         public benefitSection(){
             this.sectionRecordType='';
             this.availableList=new list<benChoice>();
         }//END init()


    }//END benefitSection

    public beneficChoice { // INNER wrapper  
        public boolean selected {get;set;}
        public Benefit__c benefit {get;set;}

        public benefitChoice(){ this.selected=false; this.benefit=new Benefit__c()} // END init()
        public benefitChoice(Benefit__c benefit){
            this.selected=false;
            this.benefit=benefit;
        }//END init(Benefit__c benefit)
    }//END benefitChoice

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public Cntrlr_SelectWhatYouWant(){
        // initialize all of the benefitSections
        // and initialize each availableList within each benefitSection

    }//END init

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    public pageReference returnNull(){
        return null;
    }//END returnNull()

}//END Cntrlr_SelectWhatYouWant
```

---

Comment: How are you processing your list of selections? If you just refresh the whole page (return null) it will reinitialize everything.  Your Submit button, should do something to loop through the values and pull out the data.

Comment: returning a null pageReference won't create a new instance of my controller, so I don't think the issue is with the submit Method.  :)

Comment: Have you added a `system.debug(medicalSection);` within the `returnNull` method to verify that the member variables truly are not being set the way you expect? Also, `Map` collections work just as well as lists - but the syntax to iterate over and bind to Map data is a _tiny_ bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The following code **works** like I want it to (/think it should), so there's gotta be something wrong with my actual code (the code in the question is just a snippit of the real thing).

```
<apex:page controller="Cntrlr_testPage">
    <style>
        .hi{
            display:inline-block;
            width: 5rem; 
            height: 2rem;
            border:5px solid blue;
            margin-bottom:1rem;
            }
        .hi2{
            display:inline-block;  
        }
    </style>

    <apex:form >
        <apex:repeat value="{!section1.innerList}" var="b">
            <div class="hi">
                <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!b.selected}"/>
            </div>
            <div class="hi2" >
                <apex:outputText value="{!b.name}"></apex:outputText>
            </div><br/>
        </apex:repeat>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!doNothing}" value="Submit"/>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class Cntrlr_testPage {

public outterClass section1 {get;set;}

public class outterClass{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public list<innerClass> innerList {get;set;}

    public outterClass(){
        this.name='';
        this.innerList=new list<innerClass>();
        }//END init()  
    }//END outterClass

    public class innerClass{
        public boolean selected {get;set;}
        public string name {get;set;}

        public innerClass(){
            this.selected=false;
            this.name='';
        }//END init()

        public innerClass(string name){
            this.selected=false;
            this.name=name;
        }//END init(string name)
    }//END innerClass


    public Cntrlr_testPage(ApexPages.StandardController con){

    }//END init(ApexPages.StandardController con)

    public Cntrlr_testPage(){
        this.section1=new OutterClass();
        list<innerClass> tmpInnerList=new list<innerClass>();
        for(integer i=0;i<5;i++)
            tmpInnerList.add(new InnerClass('#'+string.valueof(i+1)));
        section1.innerList=tmpInnerList;
    }//ENd init()


    public pageReference doNothing(){
        return null;
    }//END doNothing    


}//END Cntrlr_testPage
```